# Shinui and Shemittah: Is there such a thing?

Tags: halacha, shabbat, derabanan, shmita, shinuy-deviation

I don't remember the exact words used in the *pesukim* to describe *shemittah*, but I do remember that it uses a very similar *lashon* to *shemirat Shabbat*. As in, it is forbidden to work the land because of a sabbatical year.

Since they both seem to use similar language, my question is as follows:

On *Shabbat* it is forbidden to perform a *melakhah* on a Biblical level (i.e. an "*av*" *melakhah*). However, if it is performed with a *shinui* then it's only rabbinically prohibited. Do the same rules apply to *shemittah* (i.e. does prohibited labor during the seventh year become only rabbinically prohibited when done in an unusual manner)?

Comment: Can you look up the relevant verses and [edit] them in? Shouldn't take too long.